# Missing "Stack settings" in Azure Function App in Azure Portal

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I want to change .NET runtime. Unfortunately, settings are not visible in General setting in Function App Azure Portal.

[image]

There should be `Stack settings` group:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to migrate function worker to isolated mode. You can easily (but not intuitively!) done it by setting FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME option in the Application setting to `dotnet-isolated` (previously it was `dotnet`).

[image]

Save and the Stack settings will appear:

[image]

Comment: Do you know why I have net framework as a .net version , cs proj is tartegting to .net 8,  function_worker_runtime -:dotnet-isolated ?